# IE is not loading the right image, using <picture>

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, picturefill

I want to use jxr, webp and jp2 format in all browsers.

I've tried to use picture tag and picturefill to resolved this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script async=true src="picturefill.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <picture>
            <!--[if IE 9]><video style='display: none;'><![endif]-->
            <source type="image/webp" srcset="img.webp">
            <source type="image/jxr" srcset="img.jxr">
            <source type="image/jp2" srcset="img.jp2">
            <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
            <img src="img.jpg" alt="alt description">
        </picture>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Chrome and Firefox it shows the webp image, but in IE and Edge it always shows the jpg image. IE supports jxr format, so why always shows the JPG image instead jxr?

Comment: thats why I use picturefill.min.js http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/

Comment: IE does not support the Picture tag. I understand that you are using the picture fill api to use the picture tag in IE 9. If it is not showing the expected result than I think it is the issue with picture fill api and IE is not responsible for this behavior. It is recommended to use IE 11 (latest version) and use the img tag for displaying image in IE. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture